# Multiple websockets in QML

Tags: c++, qt, websocket, qml

I understand that it's probably a trivial question but maybe someone knows how to handle multiple websocket clients in server-qml. I did not understand from the official documentation of Qt as NOT using the C++ function or webchannel to do it. Is it possible?

I have a websocket client and server in the program. If I connect from js code to html page(from the simplechat example) how do I send a socket inside the QML app and back. How to handle the name of each socket on the server and send to it the desired text. I would appreciate any help.

My current code.

```
 WebSocketServer {
    id: server
    listen: true
    port:1234

    onClientConnected: {

        webSocket.onTextMessageReceived.connect(function(message) {
            appendMessage(qsTr("Server received message: %1").arg(message));
            webSocket.sendTextMessage(qsTr("Hello Client!"));
         // how to get a list of sockets and an instance of a particular connected socket
        });
    }
    onErrorStringChanged: {
        appendMessage(qsTr("Server error: %1").arg(errorString));
    }


}





WebSocket {
    id: socket
    url: server.url
    active:true
    onTextMessageReceived: appendMessage(qsTr("Client received message: %1").arg(message))
    onStatusChanged: {
        if (socket.status == WebSocket.Error) {
            appendMessage(qsTr("Client error: %1").arg(socket.errorString));
        } else if (socket.status == WebSocket.Closed) {
            appendMessage(qsTr("Client socket closed."));
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that there is a page with the following code something like a chat client

```
        var wsUri = "ws://localhost:1234";
        var websocket = null;

        function initWebSocket() {
            try {
                if (typeof MozWebSocket == 'function')
                    WebSocket = MozWebSocket;
                if ( websocket && websocket.readyState == 1 )
                    websocket.close();
                websocket = new WebSocket( wsUri );
                websocket.onopen = function (evt) {
                    debug("CONNECTED");
                };
                websocket.onclose = function (evt) {
                    debug("DISCONNECTED");
                };
                websocket.onmessage = function (evt) {
                    console.log( "Message received :", evt.data );
                    debug( evt.data );
                };
                websocket.onerror = function (evt) {
                    debug('ERROR: ' + evt.data);
                };
            } catch (exception) {
                debug('ERROR: ' + exception);
            }
        }
```

Its websocket creates client and connects to the server described. When a client connects from a js script, it can send a message to the server and take QML will be displayed in the hearth of the page. When a new client socket inside QML application connects to the server and sents to the alias in the message QML server and can receive messages from the server. But how to do so from the socket in the application message reached the customer at the js and back. To do this, probably it is necessary to the server as a defined desired socket, take the instance

```
webSocket.sendTextMessage(qsTr("Hello Client!"));
```

of the socket it is

Comment: I have trouble understanding your problem. What do you mean by "how to send another websocket in html page, all clients"?

Comment: Isn't `webSocket` parameter of the [`onClientConnected`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebsockets-websocketserver.html#clientConnected-signal) slot, what are you looking for? You need to store each connected, and remove them if they are closed.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I understand what to do but I'm just starting to work in qt C++ and QML. In theory, Yes I understand, and practice how to write it.I don't know.

Comment: It was necessary to simply add .js file to the global content. 
Thank you!!!